# How to subscribe to the value of a closed modal

Tags: angular

I´m switching from using Promises to Observables and have a problem understanding how to subscribe to modal values, this is my current code. I marked HERE in the second example, where the value stays undefined.

Modal TS:

```
  onEditSave(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
      console.error('Invalid form-data: ', this.formGroup);
      return;
    }

    const item: ItemDto = {
      _id: this.currentItem._id,
      item_id: this.formGroup.get('new_item_id').value,
      item_description: this.formGroup.get('new_item_description').value,
      [...]
      item_time: this.formGroup.get('new_item_time').value,
      item_arrival: this.formGroup.get('new_item_arrival').value
    };
    this.dialogRef.close(item);
  }
```

Component TS:

```
openEditDialog(item: ItemDto): void {
    const dialogRef = this.editDialog.open<EditComponent, ItemDto, ItemDto>(EditComponent, {
      data: {
        _id: item._id,
        item_id: item.item_id,
        item_description: item.item_description,
        [...]
        item_time: item.item_time,
        item_arrival: item.item_arrival
      }
    });
    
    // Here
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => { this.editResult = data });

    if (!!this.editResult) {
      try {
        this.itemsService.updateItem(this.editResult);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in the `subscribe` is an asynchronous operation, and in your example it will be executed later than the check in the `if`. So you need to move if-statement inside:

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
  this.editResult = data;

  if (!!this.editResult) {
    try {
      this.itemsService.updateItem(this.editResult);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thx Eugene, that leads to another point, because the updateItem-Method doesn´t fire. This is my method: updateItem(item: ItemDto): void {
    this.httpClient.put<ItemDto>(`${environment.serviceHost}/Items/${item._id}`, item, httpOptions);
  }. I tested the API with Postman and it works. I also have no call of the Route in the network dev tools. Do you have an idea? Regards

Comment: Looks like you have no subscription. `updateItem() { return this.httpClient... }`, `this.service.updateItem().subscribe()`.